# Least squares Levenburg Marquardt with Apache commons

Tags: java, apache-commons, least-squares

I'm using the non linear least squares Levenburg Marquardt algorithm in java to fit a number of exponential curves (A+Bexp(Cx)). Although the data is quite clean and has a good approximation to the model the algorithm is not able to model the majority of them even with a excessive number of iterations(5000-6000). For the curves it can model, it does so in about 150 iterations.

```
LeastSquaresProblem problem = new LeastSquaresBuilder()
        .start(start).model(jac).target(dTarget)
        .lazyEvaluation(false).maxEvaluations(5000)
        .maxIterations(6000).build();

LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer optimizer = new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer();
LeastSquaresOptimizer.Optimum optimum = optimizer.optimize(problem);}
```

My question is how would I define a convergence criteria in apache commons in order to stop it hitting a max number of iterations?

Comment: Impossible - that depends on your data and the initial guess you make to start with.

Comment: see edit, I don't mean giving me an exact solution more like some java tech help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Java is your problem.  Let's address the mathematics.

This problem is easier to solve if you change your function.

Your assumed equation is:

```
y = A + B*exp(C*x)
```

It'd be easier if you could do this:

```
y-A = B*exp(C*x)
```

Now A is just a constant that can be zero or whatever value you need to shift the curve up or down.  Let's call that variable z:

```
z = B*exp(C*x)
```

Taking the natural log of both sides:

```
ln(z) = ln(B*exp(C*x))
```

We can simplify that right hand side to get the final result:

```
ln(z) = ln(B) + C*x
```

Transform your (x, y) data to (x, z) and you can use least squares fitting of a straight line where `C` is the slope in (x, z) space and `ln(B)` is the intercept.  Lots of software available to do that.

Comment: great tip, however A is very important to what I'm looking for, how do you get it back from the transformation?

Comment: I think it's a translation of the fitted curve up or down on the y-axis to match the data.  Should that constant be the y value at x = 0 of your data?  The asymptotic value?  An average?  Maybe a second fit using the B and C values you get to determine A?  I don't know.  Why not try this approach and see what you get?

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'll give all of the above a go!

Comment: If nothing else, it'll give you a better starting guess for your non-linear optimization on the original equation.  Maybe you can take the best results you get out of it and stuff those into the iterative solution as your starting guess.  Non-linear methods converge faster if you happen to guess a starting point that's not far from the true solution.